# How can I geolocate if the address, zip and city are in different input fields

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I need to seperate the inputs of the address, zip and city. Now I would like to know how I can gelocate. At the Google Devleloper [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple) there is only one input field. Does anybody know how I can geolocate with three input fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just concatenate the three fields into one string...
Something like this should work fine, given a valid `API_KEY`

```
<label for="street">Street: </label><input type="text" id="street" /><br/>
<label for="city">City: </label><input type="text" id="city" /><br/>
<label for="zip">Zip code: </label><input type="text" id="zip" /><br/>
<label for="submit">Submit: </label><input type="submit" id="submit" /><br/>

<div id="map"></div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&"></script>

<script>
  window.addEventListener('load', initMap, false);

  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 8,
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644}
    });
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
      geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
    });
  }

  function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
    // CONCATENATE ADDRESS HERE
    var address = document.getElementById('street').value + ' ' +
                  document.getElementById('city').value + ' ' +
                  document.getElementById('zip').value;

    geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: resultsMap,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
      } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one with 3 Fields Based on your Request. With Address, City, Zip Code. I have changed the Latency to Brooklin New York in United States.

Best of Luck

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Geocoding service</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
#floating-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="floating-panel">


      Address: <input id="address" type="textbox" value="United States">
      City: <input id="city" type="textbox" value="New York">
      Zip Code: <input id="zip" type="textbox" value="11206">

      <input id="submit" type="button" value="Geocode">
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: {lat: 40.692129, lng: -73.5376278}
  });
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
    geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
  });
}

function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {



  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  var city = document.getElementById('city').value;
  var zip = document.getElementById('zip').value;

  geocoder.geocode({'address': address + ", " + city + " " + zip}, function(results, status) {

    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: resultsMap,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
      });

    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=ADD YOUR API KEY HERE&signed_in=true&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```